# Writing on json file with libgdx

Tags: java, android, json, libgdx, writer

I'm new on this forum and I make an android app using libgdx and I want to save the player score on a json file.
I can read the json file to get back the score but if the player do a better score I don't know how to write the new best score on the json file.
I searched on many websites and I didn't find something good...

My json file is like that :

```
{ "scores":[
  {
    "level":1,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":2,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":3,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":4,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":5,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":6,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":7,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":8,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":9,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":10,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":11,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":12,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":13,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":14,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":15,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":16,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":17,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":18,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":19,
    "bestScore":100
  },
  {
    "level":20,
    "bestScore":100
  }
  ]
}
```

And for example, if the player do a score of 30 in the level 1, I want to replace the "100" from the level 1 by "30".

I hope somebody will can help me !
Thank you, I'm waiting for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I may suggest you slightly different approach for that.
I assume that you use [Libgdx Json Api](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Json.html).
First of all we need Java representation of json, something like:

```
public class JsonResult {
    private ObjectMap<String, Integer> scores;

    public ObjectMap<String, Integer> getScores() {
        return scores;
    }

    public void setScores(ObjectMap<String, Integer> scores) {
        this.scores = scores;
    }
}
```

Here in the `scores` map the key is a `level_` prefix with actual level number (e.g. `level_1`) and the value is a score for that level.

This way your json structure would be similar to:

```
{  
   "scores":{  
      "level_1":100,
      "level_2":100,
      "level_3":200,
      "level_4":300
       ....
}
```

So, then when you save new score:

```
public void saveResult(Integer level, Integer newScore) {
    JsonResult jsonResult = json.fromJson(JsonResult.class, resultJson);
    ObjectMap<String, Integer> scores = jsonResult.getScores();
    String levelKey = "level_" + level;
    Integer scoreForLevel = scores.get(levelKey);
    if (newScore > scoreForLevel) {
         scores.put(levelKey, newScore);
         jsonResult.setScores(scores);
         json.toJson(jsonResult, resultJson);
    }
}
```

The logic is quite simple:

1. Parse `JsonResult` object from file
2. Get the score for the level from that object
3. Compare with the new score and rewrite if needed.

To create new json file:

```
public void resetResultFile() {
    JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult();
    ObjectMap<String, Integer> initialScores = new ObjectMap<>(1);
    initialScores.put("level_1", 0);
    jsonResult.setScores(initialScores);
    json.toJson(jsonResult, resultJson);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response !
But I'm doing this and it's not working, I have "error reading file, Caused by fiels not found scores".
Do you have an idea why ?

Is this ok, for the start : Json json = new Json();
  FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal("scores.json");
     JsonResult jsonResult = json.fromJson(JsonResult.class, handle);
     ObjectMap<String, Integer> scores = JsonResult.getScores();?

Comment: @Adrien you need to recreate results file, see my updated answer. I do it during the loading screen, check is the file exists and if not - create a new one. And your old json file is not valid for this new structure hence should be deleted.